# Unpaired t-Test with equal sample sizes and unequal variances

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation

I have two samples of $n=10$ with the following values

Sample 1:

- Mean = $3$
- $s_{d} = 0.4$

Sample 2:

- Mean = $3.35$
- $s_{d} = 0.3$

but the observations of both samples are unknown and I want to know the common $s_{d}$ to calculate $t_{0}$

---

Note:
this is no homework is only an exercise from the tutorial, which has not been solved.

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: no it's normal exercise

Comment: What is this $t_0$?

Comment: $t_{0} = (d- µ_{0}) / (s_{d} / \sqrt{n})$ for paired t-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i may suggest the following solution

$$ s_{d_{1}-d_{2}} = \sqrt{1/_n * (s_{d1}^2 + s_d{2}^2)} = \sqrt{1/_{10} * (0.4^2 + 0.3^2)} = 0.158 $$

$$ t = d_{1} - d_{2} / s_{d_{1}-d_{2}} = -0.35 / 0.158 = -2.215 $$

source: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#Equal_or_Unequal_sample_sizes.2C_unequal_variances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_Unequal_sample_sizes.2C_unequal_variances)

Comment: This unfortunately is incorrect.  The duplicate question shows how to combine the SDs into a pooled SD, because their *squares* are variances and that thread concerns combining variances.

Comment: i still not sure if my solution was correct, but the thread that you sepposed is not the same as my problem, as he has 2 matrices with all values $(x_{i}, y_{i})$ but i have only the SDs and the means

Comment: Your problem is *identical* to that one, but happens to be much simpler: the squares of your SDs are one-by-one covariance matrices and your means are the means of vectors of dimension 1.

Comment: [this][1] what i was looking for [1] = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#Equal_or_Unequal_sample_sizes.2C_unequal_variances